# Android capture and send notifications through bluetooth

Tags: android, serialization, android-notifications, android-bluetooth, parcelable

I have two android devices. I have developed two codebases. One is the sender codebase and the other the receiver. Both these are connected via Bluetooth Socket connection and I am able to send simple Strings between them.

On the sender device I have implemented a [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService) which captures notifications from that device. I am getting an object of type [StatusBarNotification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/StatusBarNotification) for each notification. As per the documentation, this object implements the Parcelable interface.

In order to transmit this object, I have tried using GSON, as well as using Parcel object to marshall and send the data. This was not working, so I stopped worrying about the sending part, and tried to see on the same device whether this would marshall and unmarshall correctly.

Here is the Kotlin code for both,

```
/*
 * Using Gson for serialization.
 * 
 * Parts of the object e.g. deserializedObject.notification are missing
 */
val serializedString = Gson().toJson(sbn)
val deserializedObject = Gson().fromJson<StatusBarNotification>(serializedString, StatusBarNotification::class.java)
```

```
/*
 * Using Parcel for serialization.
 *
 * Throws this error,
 * Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Tried to marshall a Parcel that contained Binder objects.
 */
val parcel = Parcel.obtain()
parcel.writeValue(sbn)
val bytes = parcel.marshall()

val p2 = Parcel.obtain()
p2.unmarshall(bytes, 0, bytes.size)
val result = p2.readValue(StatusBarNotification::class.java.classLoader) as StatusBarNotification
```

Any direction would be appreciated.

**Update 1**

I have tried creating a custom data class object. Serialization and deserialization for that works perfectly fine over bluetooth, and I am getting the data on the 2nd device. However I have narrowed it down and my problem remains that the StatusBarNotification object does not play well with serialization.

`val serializedCode = Gson().toJson(statusBarNotification)`
in debugger gives
`{"id":1815187780,"pkg":"org.telegram.messenger","uid":10260}`

Any leads would be appreciated.

**Update 2**

If there is any official way to implement notification reply through Android, a guidance on that would be appreciated as well.

Comment: I am confused, what you want to achieve reply to notification from other device or serialize/deserialize correctly?

Comment: I want to reply to notification from other device. Serialize/deserialize is a necessary part of that process.

Comment: This question seems like it's too broad? Do you have snippets from your codebase of where it's actually failing or you're lost on how to continue?

Comment: Like I have mentioned in the question, I am not able to serialize the notification object. That is where it is failing.

Comment: If you could please share the code for serialization/deserialization of the data class, it would be a huge favor. Mine gets corrupted and throws an error once I receive it on the other device.

Answer (score 1):

The status bar notification object does not necessarily represent anything meaningful on another device even if deserialized correctly. That's because it contains contextual information such as user and process IDs which are not the same on another device.

EDIT: The reason the Parcel serialization fails is because, as the error message suggests, there is a Binder object which can't be serialized (into a byte array). The json serialization probably fails for the same reason. Not all resources/objects can be serialized, or makes sense to serialize. There may be a way to retrieve the Notification object via its ID, in which case it would be enough to save just that.

What you could do is send just the essential information of the notification as string to the second devices, on the second device create a new notification to which the user can answer, send just the answer as string back to the first device, try to use that answer as a reply with the original status bar notification.

In general, this is something that is possible with smartwatches and chromebooks. Perhaps it would be helpful to have a look at how it is done in WearOS

Comment: Yes I am using another custom object to transmit over bluetooth and that is working perfectly. However when the reply comes I still need to retrieve the original sbn object from some local storage on the origin android device. This is because it contains the remote inputs and the pending intent with which we can push the reply to the originating app (say whatsapp). I will need to serialize and deserialize in that case.

Yes, looking into how Wear OS does it is the next step for me.

Comment: So I've misunderstood at least part of the question.
Do you need to marshall the notification? In a lot of situations the right way to transmit the objects is to just pass the parcel/parceable as is.

Comment: I apologize if my question was not clear enough. I created it at an early stage and since then learnt a lot more about this situation as I kept banging away at it.

If there is a way to serialize the sbn object into a list that is persisted to disk, (or shared storage) that would solve my problem.

`val serializedCode = Gson().toJson(statusBarNotification)` in debugger gives `{"id":1815187780,"pkg":"org.telegram.messenger","uid":10260}` and is not giving me the full object

Comment: Not sure if that is possible, but my understanding is lacking.
As you can see in the error you posted "Tried to marshall a Parcel that contained Binder objects." There is a Binder object which can't be serialized. The json serialization probably fails for the same reason. Not all resources/objects can be serialized. My guess is that what you need to do in such situation is to store the ID of the notification and later "ask" the Android System to give/recreate the object that corresponds to the ID instead of you deserializing it. But I'm not sure what's hiding inside the notification ...

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I guess that was the problem all along. I will try to search in that direction too. 

Sadly the bounty time is over, so I can't give you that. Would you like to rephrase your answer with details in your latest comment and I can at least mark it as the solution. Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm glad if I managed to help in some way, but I don't feel like I have provided an (good) answer. Thanks for the offer :) ! I'd suggest you post an answer yourself when you find a solution to your task.